# ion-popover window not showing

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have created an ion-popover with the following coding...

In my case, when i click on the setting button, the background will become grey as default but no options / window is popped up. The grey background will release when i click on an empty space.

Please check the following coding of mine: 
[Link to Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V8smTbsNFDgqaMduEmK2?p=preview)

```
<div class="buttons" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <button class="button icon ion-gear-a" ng-click="popover.show($event)" ng-controller="AppCtrl"></button></div>
```

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Can you please share your controller's code?

Comment: Hi, Cherry, thank you for your reply. I have included my controller's code in the plunker link inside the script.js, please check!

Comment: Did the controller working? I think it's not

Comment: I have made some modifications on it, but the window still did not show up

Comment: The codepen code is not working in plunker

Comment: Sorry I have added it back. But actually I have included all the necessary things in my project but it still doesn't work, oops:(

Comment: I have posted an answer. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have foud the solution. You have included `script.js` before angular loads. Load it after `angular.js`

```
<script src="ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

[image: See the working plunker and I just changed the above lines, please make sure that the <code>src</code> is correct as shown in the plunker's snapshot]

Comment: Thank you for your help... but I have tried it didn't work :(

Comment: No, the plunker code will work if you change these two lines. Tell me if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: Oh, i have included a bootstrap link in my script... if I uncommented it, it will work. Thank you so much for your help and your time! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.openPopover = function($event) {
    $scope.popover.show($event);
}
```

And change the ng-click to:

```
 ng-click="openPopover($event)"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it didn't work :( the grey background appears but still no popup window is showing